# How can I add reference with both number and text in LaTeX?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

How can I add reference with both number and text in LaTeX? 
The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1491890/18113340) uses hyperref but unfortunately it doesn't automatically add the section number.

Comment: Simply use `\ref` or `\ref*` and `\nameref` in the sentence (`\ref*` doesn't produce a hyperlink).

Comment: use two reference commands \ref{label}~\nameref{label}.